# Create new column based on condition and give new column a sum of a created value of existing column and a self created value

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create a new column based on a condition of another condition, creating a new column by giving it a self-determined value and (a part of) the value of an existing column.
My code looks like this:

```
Output <- mutate(data, new variable = if_else(variableA=="A", "0.060 + VariableC*0.03",
                                      if_else(variableA=="B", "0.050",
                                               "NA")))
```

This code works when I create a new variable with the values 0.060 and 0.050 (without the part 'VariableC*0.03).

However, I want the variable 'VariableC' also multiplied by 0.03 and summed up by the value 0.060 for A.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Tried it without quotation marks, but it isn't working either.

Comment: One name is a lower-case "v" and the other is upper-case "V", are you certain that the names are case-correct? FYI, you say "it isn't working", we can't help if we don't have more information. Please make this *reproducible* including sample data and the literal text of errors/warnings. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: It could also be that this code does not parse correctly: `new variable` cannot be a variable name with an embedded space. If you need that space, then you need to enclose it in backticks here as in `mutate(data, \`new variable\` = if_else(...))`.

Comment: I understand that making a question reproducible will help for better answers, however my data is personal and therefore I cannot share it. Maybe I can show my problem with a more general dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the major issue you made here is enclosing the resulting values in quotes. This treats them like they are literal strings. Also, use `NULL` to keep the type `double` for your `new_variable`.
Try this:

```
Output <- mutate(data, 
  new_variable = if_else(variableA=="A", 0.060 + VariableC * 0.03,
                         if_else(variableA=="B", 0.050, NULL)))
```

This works for me with a different dataset, which you can try out:

```
library(dslabs)
data(murders)
Output <- murders %>% mutate(
  new_variable = if_else(
   state == "Alabama",
   0.060 * total * 0.03,
   if_else(state == "Alaska", 0.050, NULL))
)
```